# How to get transform values that would be set from inserting visual key-frame for pose bones?

Tags: python, rigging, mathematics

I have some bones with any number of constraints.
I want to get the visual transform matrix of that bones that takes also into account when for example a stretch to constraint modifies that bone.

So basically the output of setting keyframes with Visual LocRotScale setting.

This would be really helpfull for exporting bone data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page of [PoseBone.matrix](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bpy.types.PoseBone.html#bpy.types.PoseBone.matrix) says

> Final 4x4 matrix after constraints and drivers are applied (object space)

<s>You can convert the matrix from object space to local space calling [Object.convert_space](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.convert_space)</s>

### Edit

The comment of `convert_space` explicitly states that this can not be used for visual keyframing. For the simplest options with

- Inherit Rotation
- Inherit Scale

enabled. You can get the local transform for the bone like this

[image: bone properties]

```
def get_mat_offset(pose_bone):
    """ calculate the (local) rest matrix of the bone 
        needs to be multiplied with the parent's pose matrix
        to get the rest matrix in armature space """
    bone = pose_bone.bone
    mat_offset = bone.matrix.to_4x4()
    mat_offset.translation = bone.head.copy()
    mat_offset.translation.y += bone.parent.length
    return mat_offset

pb = obj.pose.bones['Bone.001']

if pb.parent:
    mat_offset = get_mat_offset(pb)
    mat_pose_parent = pb.parent.matrix

    mat_rest_inv = mat_pose_parent * mat_offset
    mat_rest_inv.invert()

    matrix_basis = mat_rest_inv * pb.matrix

else:
    matrix_basis = pb.bone.matrix_local.inverted() * pb.matrix
```

Further you can decompose the matrix calling [mathutils.Matrix.decompose](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.decompose)

```
loc, rot, scale = mat_basis.decompose()
```

Comment: This answer was incorrect. An (unvalidated) python port of blender's posing code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/pink-vertex/5cd991bad102d3c260af8205ba989464).